# Excel spreadsheet: Find lowest character value and from specific cells, not specific cell range

Tags: excel-formula

I have a range of cell {B15:G15) with the following values.

B15   B16   B17   B18   B19   B20

C     D     B     C     D     F

I would like to use a formula to find the lowest value character from few specific cells (only B15, B17, B19), not from the range (B15:G15).
In the above example, the answer should be “B”.

What could be the formula, any suggestion ?

Thank you.

Regards,
w

Comment: Will it always be uppercase letters only? if so, create a helper column (say column C) with =CODE(B15) copied down next to your range. Then somewhere else put =CHAR(MIN(C15,C17,C19)). (You can also delete the "unused" cells in C if you feel like it)

Comment: Yes, always in uppercase. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the lowest value character in cells B15, B17 and B19 only

Input data housed in `B15:B20`

[image]

In `D15`, enter formula :

```
=CHAR(MIN(CODE(T(OFFSET(B14,{1,3,5},0)))))
```